# VBA - Loop through column and insert a row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I just want to insert a new line in each row of a column (beginning with the third row below the header). But instead, the macro adds n-new columns in the third row, n being the number of rows in the column. I have another macro with the same loop to insert a hyperlink in each cell, which works absolute fine, now I am drawing a blank...

What could be the reason?

```
Sub InsertRows()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 3  

    Do

    Range("C" & i).Select


    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

    i = i + 1
    Loop Until i > lRow


End Sub
```

Comment: What's `celltext` in `If InStr(1, celltext, "Aleman") > 0 Then`?

Comment: Don't use `ActiveCell` either; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) should be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry, this is a left over. Next step, is checking the value for a specific string before inserting a new row.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to insert a new row at the **beginning** of *any existing row* and following the existing code logic, you could try the following *(I don't pretend this to be the best way to do so)*:

```
Sub InsertRows()

'Fully qualify your Range references
With Sheet1                 ' Using e.g. the project sheet's Code(Name)
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    i = 3
    'Define the resulting end row
    Dim eRow As Long
    eRow = 2 * lRow - i + 1

    Do
        .Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Insert
        i = i + 2                   ' increment in double steps
    Loop Until i > eRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Posted a solution to your insertion issue caused by the fact that you have to move in double steps; feel free to upv./accept by ticking the green checkmark if helpful - @programmierboy